# how can i print in javascript a string in parts

Tags: javascript, string-length

I have an exercise from my university that i have a string let's say i have that: "hello" and i want to print it like that:

hhehelhellhello (h he hel hell hello).

the thing that i stack is that they want to do it without loop!

Anyone can help me? :/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<script>
var strin = "hello" 
for (i = 0; i < strin.length; i++) {
   document.write(strin.slice(0,i+1))
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a trick question ?

Comment: i don't really know ... i thought that i can print it one by one but i want to kill myself before i do it :P

Comment: I guess You will need to use recursion. Will try to write a solution for it after office

Comment: you have to use a function for sure...

Comment: thank you all for your answers. 
@Vatsal i'll be waiting for your answer if you thing something. 
thnx againa

Comment: you should pay attention in class

Comment: Something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/kktt8n94/

Comment: @mikevorisis - Posted my answer :) Hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use recursion. Code:

```
function r (s, i) {
 if (i == undefined) i = 0;
 if (i == s.length) return "";
 return s.slice(0, i + 1) + r(s, i + 1);
}

r("hello"); // hhehelhellhello
```

Comment: Given that this looks suspiciously like a homework question, giving straight, runnable code might not be the best idea. Good short answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try a recursive approach:

```
function print(word, step){
    if(word.length<step) return;
    console.log(word.substring(1, step));
}
print('hello', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a more efficient solution, but off the top of my head this should work:

```
var s = "hello";
var index = 0;
var len = 1;
var newString = '';

function appendToResult(str, index, len) {
  newString += str.slice(index, len);
  len++;
  if (len !== s.length + 1) {
    appendToResult(s, index, len);
  }
}

appendToResult(s, index, len);
console.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you met.... Recursion?

What you need to achieve is something like this (for a string "hello"):

```
h
he
hel
hell
hello
```

A recursive call to a method (say, `myPrinter()`) could behave similarly:

```
call myPrinter(hello):
  call myPrinter(hell):
    call myPrinter(hel):
      call myPrinter(he):
        call myPrinter(h):
          print 'h'
        print 'he'
      print 'hel'
    print 'hell'
  print 'hello'
done
```

So how do we go about writing this magical method of ours?

Take notice that at each call we make another call to our method but with a shorter input (in fact, the input has been truncated by one character from the end).

You could write something like this:

```
function myPrinter(myString):
  myPrinter(myString - last character of myString);
  print myString; // and maybe some space
  if myString is empty:
    return; // do nothing. just return
```

All that's left for you to do is translating the above idea into clean bug-free code.

Answer (score 0):

Of course we have to loop this way or that way. Yet in the below code it is disguised as a recursive function. Yet i am using no counting variables at all. It has the potential to deceive inexperienced eyes. This is how i would do it;

```js
function makeStringWeird(s){
  var extend = (s, r=[]) => s !=="" ? (r.push(s),extend(s.slice(0,s.length-1),r)) : r;
return extend(s).reverse().join("");
}
console.log(makeStringWeird("hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I landed up making two solutions for you. One is by using reduce function which doesn't explicitly uses any loop but when I checked its polyfill it uses a while loop to iterate. The code for that is given below and it can also be seen at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vatsalpande/42590tre/

```
(function(){

 var convertedString = [];
  function reducer(previousValue, currentValue){
    convertedString.push(previousValue+currentValue);  
    return previousValue+currentValue;
        }

  var string = "hello";
  var stringArray = string.split("");

  var totalVersion= stringArray.reduce(reducer,"");

  console.info(convertedString.join(""));

})();
```

Since this was using iteration I created one more by using recursion alone. Below is the code and the fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/vatsalpande/tnxsuw75/

```
(function(){
var string = "hello";
var stringArray = string.split("");
var convertedValue = [];
function convert(initialValue, index){
  if(index < stringArray.length){
    convertedValue.push(initialValue+stringArray[index]);
    convert(initialValue+stringArray[index], index+1);
  }
}
convert("",0);
console.info(convertedValue.join(""));
})();
```

Hope these be of some help.

Any feedback to improve them is highly appreciated.

Happy Learning :)